# Gitlab CI CD pick up a branch in a different project

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-delivery

I'm trying to setup a `CI/CD` pipeline for my project. Currently the stages implemented are `build` and `test`. I'm using `Gradle` with `Spring boot`. I have the following requirements. Let's call the current project Project A

- Pipeline has to pick up the master branch on Project B and builds the jars and adds them to Project A's lib directory.
- Deploy to a remote machine using a specific application.properties file (Let's call it `remote-application.properties`)

I have a few questions regarding these requirements :-

- Should the CI CD pipeline be implemented for Project B also? Currently it isn't implemented for Project B
- How do I specify the `application.properties` file specific to remote machine in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

I went through https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html

But I'm still not sure on how to implement these requirements. Any help in this would be appreciated.

Using GitLab premium version

Comment: First question is which version of GitLab are you using? Note that multi project pipelines feature is available in paid Gitlab Premium version.

Comment: @makozaki using GitLab premium

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question:

> How do I specify the application.properties file specific to remote
>   machine in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

Jobs in GitLab CI clone your git repository and then execute command line scripts. You can either choose to include the whole file in your git repository, or keep it separate in some way. One alternative is to use [file type environment variable in GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#file-type). The information in the file would then be kept outside of git, which is good if this file contains secrets.

When you have the file available in your GitLab job, you should be able to execute the command just as if you were using the command line on your local machine.

For the first part of your question:

> Should the CI CD pipeline be implemented for Project B also? Currently
>   it isn't implemented for Project B

Yes. Implement a pipeline for Project B as well. It should be quite easy for you to make a pipeline for Project B that builds and stores the artifacts for that project. Project A can then download those files using the [GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#download-the-artifacts-archive). A short example that I haven't tested, but that should put you on the right track:

```
//.gitlab-ci.yml of Project B
build_master:
  script:
    - make
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - project_b_jars
  only:
    refs
      - master

//.gitlab-ci.yml of Project A
build:
  script:
    - 'curl --location --output artifacts.zip --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_B_PROJECT_ID>/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=build_master"'
```

I think that this solution is the easiest to set up and that fits your needs. When you have this, it should also be possible to expand to a multi-project pipeline if you need to do so.

Another alternative is to set up PROJECT_B as a submodule of PROJECT_A. You would then have total control of which version of PROJECT_B that is used in PROJECT_A, which is good if you are working with for example firmware.